# PyTest Allert / Message Box

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, pywin32

My code generates an Alert / Message Box using the code below.

```
import win32api
win32api.MessageBox(0, 'You have reached the end of the data.', 'End of Data')
```

Is there a way to test that the message appears e.g. something like `assert appears`? Ideally I'd like to do this using PyTest, however solutions using other frameworks would still be greatly appreciated. It would also be good to test the text within the box e.g. `assert message == "You have reached the end of the data."`

Comment: Let me know if you need more information on the answer I gave...

Answer (score 1):

You are using Windows so you can use `pywinauto` or autoit for caching the element of the message box then use `pytest` to run the test asserting the value of the message!

Here is the documentation for `pywinauto` [link](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Here is the documentation for `autoit` [link](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoIt/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. I didn't realise win32api only worked on Windows. So I've instead changed to 
`import tkinter as tk`

`from tkinter import messagebox`
`root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
messagebox.showwarning('End of Data', "You have reached the end of the data.")`

Do you know similar tools for testing that message box? I'll keep my original question as it is because I imagine someone else might find it useful. But I don't know if this change makes it worth writing a new question.

Comment: In the end I did write a second question. I thought I'd keep my original question here, in case someone else has the same issue. I've now completed the project this was relating too and have to work on other things. As such I do not currently have time to check if your solution works. I'll wait either until I have time to do my own experiments or somebody else contributes here, then I might click the accept button.